# Add external library as a target dependency and link to external library

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm trying to add external project as library to my project.

> - Add extLib as a target dependency and link to extLib.a

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the image below, go to :

`Target > Build Phases > Target Dependencies and add extLib`

`Target > Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries and add extLib.a`

You need to drag and drop the classes for extLib on your project before.

[image]